# Convert durations to start times

Tags: org-mode, time-date

## Problem

I have some org-mode tables with a column containing the duration (or length) of musical tracks:

```
|---+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------|
| # | Artist                          | Title                             | Duration |
|---+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------|
| 1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet      | consectetuer adipiscing elit      |     7:32 |
| 2 | Donec hendrerit tempor tellus   | Donec pretium posuere tellus      |  1:09:27 |
| 3 | Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et   | mattis eget, convallis nec, purus |    10:15 |
| 4 | Cum sociis natoque penatibus et | magnis dis parturient montes      |     4:25 |
|---+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------|
```

I'd like to convert the durations to start times.  The result of the converstion should look like this:

```
|---+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------|
| # | Artist                          | Title                             | Start time |
|---+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------|
| 1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet      | consectetuer adipiscing elit      |       0:00 |
| 2 | Donec hendrerit tempor tellus   | Donec pretium posuere tellus      |       7:32 |
| 3 | Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et   | mattis eget, convallis nec, purus |    1:16:59 |
| 4 | Cum sociis natoque penatibus et | magnis dis parturient montes      |    1:27:14 |
|---+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------|
```

## Note

### In the duration input

- Durations will be given in terms of **hours, minutes, and seconds, separated by colons**
- **leading zeroes may or may not be present**
  *(ie. a duration may look like "09:25" or "9:25")*
- **the hours field may or may not be present**
  *(ie. a duration might look like "9:25" or "1:09:25" or even "0:09:25")*

### In the start time output

- **minutes and seconds should always be present**, even if they're zero
  *(ex: "0:00" and "0:32" are both correct)*
- **if the left-most field is not a minute field and is 0, it and the colon following it should be omitted**
  *(ie. output "12:24", not "0:12:24")*
- **a field should be padded with leading zeroes** if there is another field to its left
  *(ie. these are all correct: "1:09:26", "1:00:26", "1:00:00", "9:26", and these are wrong: "0:09:26", "00:09:26")*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following provides `my-durations-to-start-times` to convert durations to start-times, e.g.,

```el
(my-durations-to-start-times '("7:32" "1:09:27" "10:15" "4:25"))
;; => ("0:00" "7:32" "1:16:59" "1:27:14")
```

```el
(defun my-duration-to-seconds (duration)
  "Return number of seconds of DURATION string."
  (let ((seconds 0)
        (unit 1))
    (dolist (n (nreverse (mapcar #'string-to-number (split-string duration ":"))))
      (setq seconds (+ seconds (* n unit)))
      (setq unit (* unit 60)))
    seconds))

(cl-assert (= (my-duration-to-seconds "04") 4))
(cl-assert (= (my-duration-to-seconds "7:32") (+ (* 7 60) 32)))
(cl-assert (= (my-duration-to-seconds "1:09:27") 4167))

(defun my-format-seconds (seconds)
  (let* ((h (floor seconds 3600))
         (seconds (- seconds (* 3600 h)))
         (m (floor seconds 60))
         (seconds (- seconds (* 60 m)))
         (s seconds))
    (if (zerop h)
        (format "%d:%02d" m s)
      (format "%d:%02d:%02d" h m s))))

(cl-assert (string= (my-format-seconds (my-duration-to-seconds "0")) "0:00"))
(cl-assert (string= (my-format-seconds (my-duration-to-seconds "00:09:26")) "9:26"))

(defun my-durations-to-start-times (durations)
  (let ((start 0))
    (mapcar (lambda (duration)
              (prog1 (my-format-seconds start)
                (setq start (+ start (my-duration-to-seconds duration)))))
            durations)))

(cl-assert (equal (my-durations-to-start-times '("7:32" "1:09:27" "10:15" "4:25"))
                  '("0:00" "7:32" "1:16:59" "1:27:14")))
```

Use `my-durations-to-start-times` in org-mode table formula

```
|---+----------+------------|
|   | Duration | Start time |
|---+----------+------------|
| 1 |     7:32 |       0:00 |
| 2 |  1:09:27 |       7:32 |
| 3 |    10:15 |    1:16:59 |
| 4 |     4:25 |    1:27:14 |
|---+----------+------------|
#+TBLFM: $>='(nth (1- (string-to-number $1)) (my-durations-to-start-times '(@2$>>..@5$>>)))
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you!  Not to look a gift horse in the mouth, but is it possible to just replace the durations in the Duration column with the respective start times rather than putting the start times in a separate column?

Comment: @izkon I don't know. I don't have much experience with org-mode table formula. The above formula needs to call `my-durations-to-start-times` 4 times, instead of just 1 time, it assumes the Duration column doesn't change, thus simply replacing `$>=` with `$>>=` doesn't work.

Comment: To add to @xuchunyang's comment, it is better to construct a table using a source block, instead of trying to use a formula to modify the table in place. The latter method is fraught with lurking tripping hazards and usually leads to disaster.